# Google Drive usage after opening Google's account

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api, google-drive-realtime-api

Does every user has a Google Drive space so long after he or she create a Google's account automatically? Should user open drive ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With one google account (gmail), google users have access to all of their free product (YouTube, gmail, google drive etc.,).

In case of your question, the user will always have a google drive account as long as the user has a gmail account, it is the users discretion to open the google drive account or not.